# enabling CRP.msi on SCCM gives Error 1603

Tags: sccm, scep

am trying to enable SCCM + NDES + CRP to distribute SCEP configurations.
Following steps mentioned https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/protect/deploy-use/certificate-infrastructure here.

It's when I tried to enable CRP role on my SCCM machine that I see following error:

MSI (s) (44:98) [15:37:19:638]: Product: Certificate Registration Point -- Installation operation failed.
MSI (s) (44:98) [15:37:19:639]: Windows Installer installed the product. Product Name: Certificate Registration Point. Product Version: 5.00.8790.1000. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: Microsoft Corporation. Installation success or error status: 1603.

How can we fix the 1603 error for CRP.msi, Looking on web I find nothing.

Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did following:

1. Remove CRP role.
2. Run below commamd

   Get-WMIObject -namespace "root" -query "SELECT * FROM __Namespace where name = 'ccm'" | remove-wmiobject
3. Re-enable CRP role.

It worked. No errors noticed in CRPMSI.log.